# Not load a custom control if it is collapsed

Tags: c#, xaml, custom-controls, windows-phone-8

I'm writing on windows phone 8 app which has to load a list of epgs.
To do that I am using a listbox and a datatemplate.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FooDataTemplate">
    <Button Margin="0,10,0,0" Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonNoMarginStyle}}" BorderThickness="0" Width="375" Height="105" Command="{Binding ElementName=pageRoot,Path=ViewModel.NavigateToDetailsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="195"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <controls:ImageControl ImageUri="{Binding Image}" Grid.RowSpan="2"  Grid.Column="0" />
                <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{StaticResource SecondCaptionImage}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Stretch="None"/>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding IsCurrentEpg, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle Fill="#cc3e567b" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="DIRECT" FontSize="12" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration}" FontSize="12" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,-8,0,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <!--Title-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <!--SubTitle-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <!--Hours-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <!--Progress bar if needed-->
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Text="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource CaseStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=Upper}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Text="{Binding Subtitle, Converter={StaticResource CaseStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=Upper}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding DurationTitle}"/>
                <Grid Margin="-4,0,0,0" Grid.Row="3" Visibility="{Binding IsCurrentEpg, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" >
                    <controls:EpgProgressBar Visibility="{Binding IsCurrentEpg, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"  Loaded="SecondProgressBarLoaded" IsEnabled="{Binding IsCurrentEpg}"  CurrentEpg="{Binding}"  Width="375" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

As you can see I uses one EpgProgressBar and I shows it only if it's the current epg. The view is correctly set and I only get the progress bar for the current epg. But, I can see in my output that each button has one progress bar.

Is there a way to no load an custom control (in my case progress bar) if this control is collapsed or hidden?

Regards.

Comment: Just to clarify, is 'EPG' a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_program_guide ?

Comment: Yes, it is a list of tv program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, a control actually placed on the View will be created/loaded regardless of its state. So, directly, no, there's no way.

But, you can achieve the effect by targetting not 'Visibility' but the "placing it on the View" itself.

Do not initialize and pre-place everything on startup and do not change the Visibility depending on various state changes. That leaves you with tons of ui elements where most of them are .. hidden.

Instead, leave holes. Replace those elements that are typically hidden with placeholders, i.e. ContentControl or ContentPresenter, then prepare styles/templates for those placeholders: at least one with your desired proper content (i.e. progressbar) and optionally a second (with button "clickme"). You do not need a 'an empty' one just to make the placeholder empty. Finally, any time you'd like to switching the content's "Visibility" - switch the placeholder's `Content` property instead to activate either viewtemplate#1 or viewtemplate#2, or `null` to leave placeholder empty.

I sometimes like to call them microviews to differentiate from "big" views that build the overall application, but in fact, this is almost the same mechanism, and in fact core of WPF's content displaying.

The net effect will be, at least:

- if not needed (content=null), nothing loaded (except for lightweight placeholder)
- when needed (content=myprogressbardata), the correct contents are shown (mytemplate_with_progressbar)
- you can easily extend the viewstructure with new content types (just set different content types -> get different microview types visible)
- styles and templates can be switched on and off in a myriad of ways; they can be bound to a datatype, they can be set via triggers, can be inherited from upper styles, (...)

Disadvantages:

- actual microviews are in form of templates. This makes data/event/command binding harder, but still possible, still by XAML means